# How to stop single node kubernetes cluster gracefully

Tags: kubernetes

I've set up single node kubernetes  according to [official tutorial][1].

In addition to official documentation I've set-up single node cluster:

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

Disabled eviction limit:

```
cat << EOF >> /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml
evictionHard:
  imagefs.available: 1%
  memory.available: 100Mi
  nodefs.available: 1%
  nodefs.inodesFree: 1%
EOF

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart kubelet
```

And set systemd driver for Docker:

```
cat << EOF > /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "100m"
  },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
EOF

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

How can I temporary stop Kubernetes cluster (including all it's services, podd, etc)? I've issued `systemctl stop kubelet` but I stil see some kubernetes stuff among processes

```
$ ps -elf | grep kube
4 S root       6032   5914  1  80   0 - 2653148 -    Feb17 ?        00:35:10 etcd --advertise-client-urls=https://192.168.1.111:2379 --cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt --client-cert-auth=true --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd --initial-advertise-peer-urls=https://192.168.1.111:2380 --initial-cluster=ubuntu=https://192.168.1.111:2380 --key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key --listen-client-urls=https://127.0.0.1:2379,https://192.168.1.111:2379 --listen-metrics-urls=http://127.0.0.1:2381 --listen-peer-urls=https://192.168.1.111:2380 --name=ubuntu --peer-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt --peer-client-cert-auth=true --peer-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key --peer-trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --snapshot-count=10000 --trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
4 S root       7536   7495  0  80   0 - 35026 -      Feb17 ?        00:01:04 /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf --hostname-override=ubuntu
4 S root       9868   9839  0  80   0 - 34463 -      Feb17 ?        00:00:59 /usr/bin/kube-controllers
4 S root      48394  48375  2  80   0 - 36076 -      13:41 ?        00:01:09 kube-scheduler --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf --bind-address=127.0.0.1 --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf --leader-elect=true
4 S root      48461  48436  3  80   0 - 52484 -      13:41 ?        00:01:53 kube-controller-manager --allocate-node-cidrs=true --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf --bind-address=127.0.0.1 --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --cluster-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --cluster-signing-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --cluster-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key --controllers=*,bootstrapsigner,tokencleaner --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf --leader-elect=true --node-cidr-mask-size=24 --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt --root-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --service-account-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12 --use-service-account-credentials=true
4 S root      52675  52586  7  80   0 - 123895 -     14:00 ?        00:02:01 kube-apiserver --advertise-address=192.168.1.111 --allow-privileged=true --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379 --insecure-port=0 --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra- --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User --secure-port=6443 --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12 --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
```

Comment: Which tutorial you used? Have you installed the cluster using `kubeadm`?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to stop everything what is running by kubernetes/docker for what ever reason - you can just stop both kubelet and docker.

Perform these commands on the node you like to stop kubernetes/docker

```
systemctl stop kubelet 
systemctl stop docker
```

I strongly recommend to drain the node first, but if you just like to kill everything without any caution that would be one way to stop kubernetes and the running containers on the node  :)

once you like to start everything again just start docker and kubelet again or just reboot the machine.

cheers

Comment: The above worked, but I still see `coredns` and `containerd` (though I'm using Docker) in top / htop: any suggestion?

Comment: Not really, but if you check via kubectl whether there are still pods running on these very node you would see if its cluster related or not.
Anyway, the simples way would be just to remove the node from the cluster via the delete command and then you can check/boot/delete whatever you like with those node :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `kubectl drain <node name>`

When kubectl drain returns successfully, that indicates that all of the pods have been safely evicted respecting the desired graceful termination period.

Once it returns (without giving an error), you can power down the node (or equivalently, if on a cloud platform, delete the virtual machine backing the node). If you leave the node in the cluster during the maintenance operation, you need to run

```
kubectl uncordon <node name>
```

afterwards to tell Kubernetes that it can resume scheduling new pods onto the node

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions asked in one:

- Stop kubernetes cluster and
- Temporarily stop

I will answer keeping both in mind. Also it is not clear how you created your cluster but it seems like you used `kubeadm`.

Steps:

1. As mentioned by [@arghya-sadhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839482/arghya-sadhu) & [@henry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12920792/henry), gracefull shutdown is recommended but not mandatory if this is a test cluster and you don't care about the workloads (pods,etc)

   - `kubectl cordon <node name>`
   - `kubectl drain <node name>`
2. `kubeadm` hosts master plane pods as static pods [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47602755/4451944)! `mv /etc/kubernetes/manifests/ /tmp` as explained [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/static-pod/#dynamic-addition-and-removal-of-static-pods)